# Scrapy: deny/ignore link with specific class attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am crawling a large website with scrapy and I am looking for a way to deny all  tags with an attribute class="AdvSearchKeyword_clearall".

If it is not possible to deny an `<a>` tag with class="AdvSearchKeyword_clearall", would it be possible to parse the "AdvSearchKeyword_clearall" to filter out all links with the specific attribute later?

---

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class ComSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "browsepages"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com",]

    rules = (
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/browse/', ),)
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),unique=True,deny=('/[1-9]$', '(bti=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(sort_by=)[a-zA-Z]', '(sort_by=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=32_)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=60_)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?', '(search_sort=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', 'browse-ng.do\?', '/page/', '/ip/', 'out\+value', 'fn=', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', 'search_sort=&', 'facet=' ))),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
            item['robots'] = site.select('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Comment: pls share your code, what are you using CrawlSpider? how do your rules look like?

Comment: @Guy appreciate you taking your time to look, i've edited w/ code.

Comment: @Guy Yes, I am using crawlspider.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `SgmlLinkExtractor` with following code:

```
class ExtendedSgmlLinkExtractor(SgmlLinkExtractor):
    def __init__(self, deny_xpaths=(), *args, **kwargs):
        self.deny_xpaths = deny_xpaths
        super(ExtendedSgmlLinkExtractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def extract_links(self, response):
        from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
        base_url = None

        if self.restrict_xpaths:
            sel = Selector(response)
            base_url = get_base_url(response)
            body = u''.join(f
                            for x in self.restrict_xpaths
                            for f in sel.xpath(x).extract()
                            ).encode(response.encoding)
        else:
            body = response.body

        if self.deny_xpaths:
            sel = Selector(response)
            base_url = get_base_url(response)
            body = u''.join(f
                            for x in self.deny_xpaths
                            for f in sel.xpath(x).extract()
                            ).encode(response.encoding)

        links = self._extract_links(body, response.url, response.encoding, base_url)
        links = self._process_links(links)
        return links
```

and then use it with xpaths that contains `not()` operator, in your case - `//a[not(contains(@class, 'AdvSearchKeyword_clearall'))]` like:

```
rules = (Rule(ExtendedSgmlLinkExtractor(…, deny_xpaths=('//a[not(contains(@class, 'AdvSearchKeyword_clearall'))]',),)
```

Though that code has not been tested, so please feedback in any case.

Comment: This is great, how would I implement this for 'LinkExtractor'?  When using 'LinkExtractor' in place of SgmlLinkExtractor, I get the following error: `'str' object has no attribute '_root'`

Comment: It is still parsing from the not() operator.